# change font-size and right-justification with spaces (preserve spaces)

Tags: php

I tried to change the font-size and want to justify the text at fixed positions.

Example change the font-size

```
echo "<p style='text-align: left;'><span style='font-size: large; font-family: georgia,palatino; color: #003366;'> Test georgia,palatino Size: large </span></p> </br>";
$output = sprintf ('<p style="text-align: left;"><span style="font-size: large; font-family: georgia,palatino; color: black;"> Test georgia,palatino Size: large </span></p> </br>"');
echo $output;
```

Example with str_pad

```
 $output = 'HTML to PHP';
 echo str_pad ( $output, 20, '*' ).'<br>';
 echo str_pad ( $output, 20, '*', STR_PAD_LEFT ).'<br>';
 echo str_pad ( $output, 20, '*', STR_PAD_BOTH ).'<br>';
```

Example first possibility to justify text ( works well ), at position 20 is the next text :

```
 echo  str_pad ( $output, 20, ' ',  STR_PAD_RIGHT ) .  str_pad ( $output, 20, ' ',  STR_PAD_RIGHT ) .'<br>' ;
```

Example second possibility to justify text ( works well )

```
 echo  sprintf("%-20s%-20s<br>" , $output, $output );
```

Example change the font-size of a heading ( works well )

```
 $output = sprintf ('<div align="left" > <h2><span style="text-decoration: underline;"> Left: This will be underlined.</span></h2></div>' );
 echo $output;
```

Example change font-size and justify the text at fixed positions ( doesn't ok) :

$text = 'HTML to PHP';

// ok

```
 echo '<pre>';
 echo  sprintf("%-20s%-20s<br>" , $text, $text );
```

// not ok and i haven't any idea, if it is possible to justify a text with other font-size

```
 $output = sprintf ('<p <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: georgia,palatino; color: black;"> %s </span></p>', $text);

 echo str_pad ( $output, 20, '*', STR_PAD_RIGHT ) . str_pad ( $output, 20, '*', STR_PAD_RIGHT ) ;

 echo  sprintf("%-20s%-20s<br>" , $output, $output );
```

Answer (score 0):

You just wrote `span` tag inside the p tag. You have to start the `<p>`. You didn't write `>` and started `span` within `<p <span` that is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it and test it again, but i can't justify the text at defined positions:

```
 $text = 'HTML to PHP';

 echo '<pre>';
 echo  sprintf("Test 1: %-20s%-20s<br>" , $text, $text );

 $output = sprintf ('<p> <span style="font-size: 10pt; font-family: georgia,palatino; color: black;"> %s </span></p>', $text);



// This works ok 
 echo $output;
 // This test produces a output in two lines !!!
 echo str_pad ( $output, 20, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT ) . str_pad ( $output, 20, ' ', STR_PAD_RIGHT ) ;
 // This test produces also a output in two lines !!!
 echo  sprintf("%-20s%-20s<br>" , $output, $output );
```